# setState ReactJS Material UI is not working

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have next problem. I want when I click on one MenuItem, the state of my component changes with the name of the MenuItem clicked. I do it so:

```
export default class MenuAlumno extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        drawerOpen:false,
        currentPage: 'Inicio'
    }
};

currentPages = (currentPage) => {
    this.setState({ 
        currentPage: currentPage
    });
    //this.state.currentPage = currentPage;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Drawer 
                docked = {false}
                width = {200}
                open = {this.state.drawerOpen}
                onRequestChange = {(drawerOpen) => this.setState({drawerOpen})}
            >
                <MenuItem primaryText = "Inicio" onTouchTap = {this.currentPages('Inicio')} containerElement = {<Link to="/administrador/inicio"/>}/>
                <MenuItem primaryText = "Nueva Incidencia" onTouchTap = {this.currentPages('Nueva Incidencia')} containerElement = {<Link to="/administrador/nueva_incidencia"/>}/>
                <MenuItem primaryText = "Incidencias Recibidas" onTouchTap = {this.currentPages('Incidencias Recibidas')} containerElement = {<Link to="/administrador/incidencias_recibidas"/>}/>
                <MenuItem primaryText = "Informes" onTouchTap = {this.currentPages('Informes')} containerElement = {<Link to="/administrador/informes"/>}/>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But I have next error:

`Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render' or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to 'componentWillMount'.`

What could it be? Thank you all.

EDIT: ----

If I do this: (adding ()=> begin the call function)

```
<MenuItem primaryText = "Inicio" onTouchTap = {() => this.currentPages('Inicio')} containerElement = {<Link to="/administrador/inicio"/>}/>
                <MenuItem primaryText = "Nueva Incidencia" onTouchTap = {() => this.currentPages('Nueva Incidencia')} containerElement = {<Link to="/administrador/nueva_incidencia"/>}/>
                <MenuItem primaryText = "Incidencias Recibidas" onTouchTap = {() => this.currentPages('Incidencias Recibidas')} containerElement = {<Link to="/administrador/incidencias_recibidas"/>}/>
                <MenuItem primaryText = "Informes" onTouchTap = {() => this.currentPages('Informes')} containerElement = {<Link to="/administrador/informes"/>}/>
```

I have not any error but is not working. When I click the state is not updated, continue being 'Inicio' and when I click again to the same choice the state is changed (but only when I click twice on the same option). I think it could be due to Link to other routes which re-renders again menu component. Any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: You are calling the `currentPages` function inside the `render` method. It's not allowed as it might produce an infinitive loop. I gues, your implementation is not what do you want really. Try this: `onTouchTap = {() => this.currentPages(...)}`

Comment: It will bind a _callback_ for the `onTouchTap` where you will call the `currentPages` function

Comment: Right, just now I did this, but I have next error that I have been added on my post after EDIT: . Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Not sure, but seems this is a logic issue. Elaborate what are you trying to implement, please. If you want link user to some other page, what's the benefit of setting anything into the state of the component, which will be anoumnted. If you wish relate to the state, why do you have `Link` than?

Comment: Yes, after being investigating, this is the error, as I posted after EDIT. The error is due to routes (Link) due to the component is unmounted and mounted again, so the state is the initial. How could I solve this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it adding a prop when I call my component MenuAlumno with the name that I wanna set as current page. It works. If anyone have other solution, I will be happy to try it. Bye.